# Ways to say “grandmother”?

Tags: société, surnoms

My mom grew up calling her grandmother “Citie” (I’m not sure if that’s how it’s spelled) and she thinks it was French. Is this actually the sound of a French word?  I haven’t been able to find “citie” online anywhere. It doesn’t sound anything like “grand-mere.”

Answer (score 3):

*Citie* doesn't sound like any of the common nicknames used by grandchildren to call their grandmothers.

[Here is a poll](https://www.emoi-emoi.com/mag/en-famille/les-petits-noms-de-nos-grand-meres/) that says that among the 617 families who answered, 208 different ones were used. That's quite a lot.

There is ***titi*** in the list. It is a common nickname in France, although not specifically for a grandmother. That or ***titie*** might be what your mother used anyway, especially if her grandmother's first name contained ***t*** or ***ti***.